# C# Webclient Stream download file from FTP to local storage

Tags: c#, ftp, stream, webclient

I've been downloading files from an FTP server via the `WebClient` object that the `.NET` namespace provides and then write the bytes to a actual file via a `BinaryWriter`.  All is good.  However, now, the files have dramatically increased in size and I'm worried about memory constraints so I'd like to create a download stream, create an file stream, and line by line read from the download and write to the file.

I'm nervous since I couldn't find a nice example of this. Here's my end result:

```
var request = new WebClient();

// Omitted code to add credentials, etc..

var downloadStream = new StreamReader(request.OpenRead(ftpFilePathUri.ToString()));
using (var writeStream = File.Open(toLocation, FileMode.CreateNew))
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(writeStream))
    {
        while (!downloadStream.EndOfStream)
        {
            writer.Write(downloadStream.ReadLine());                  
        }
    }
}
```

Am I going about this incorrect/better way/etc?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried the following usage of `WebClient` class?

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.DownloadFile("url", "filePath");
}
```

**Update**

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
using (var stream = client.OpenRead("..."))
using (var file = File.Create("..."))
{
    stream.CopyTo(file);
}
```

If you want to download file explicitly using customized buffer size:

```
public static void DownloadFile(Uri address, string filePath)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    using (var stream = client.OpenRead(address))
    using (var file = File.Create(filePath))
    {
        var buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesReceived;
        while ((bytesReceived = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
        {
            file.Write(buffer, 0, bytesReceived);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, and still am (the request object is a WebClient [I'm update my post to show this explictly]) but DownladFile will give me the entire file in memory--the opposite of what I'm looking for..

Comment: @OnResolve, sorry, I've not mentioned. Please see the update.

Comment: @OnResolve, I've added the version with the customized buffer size.