# Error 404 (File not found) using C# WebClient.DownloadFile

Tags: c#, ftp, webclient

I searched questions/answers that were somewhat relevant to my issue.  The one most relevant to mine resulted in emptying a file after using the C# WebClient class for a file download.  Since my issue with WebClient didn't involve emptying a file, I decided to create a new question.

I'm getting an exception from some C# code I'm experimenting with for doing an FTP file download, using the WebClient class.  The message states it's an error 404 (file not found).  The url I gave it had the correct path info.  So, to get more insight, I looked into using the WebException class to reveal more info. on why the file isn't being found.  But, its instructions are a little too cryptic.  So, since I'm new to doing FTP downloads in C#, let me show my code, and maybe someone can see something obvious to them on what might be missing from the code and causing the 404 error.  If not, I'll just go back to figuring out how to use WebException. Thanks for any help.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string remoteUri = "<myWebsite>/public_html/";
        string fileName = "<myTargetFile>", myStringWebResource = null;

        // Create a new WebClient instance.
        WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
        myWebClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("<username>", "<password>");

        // Concatenate the domain with the Web resource filename.
        myStringWebResource = remoteUri + fileName;
        Console.WriteLine("Downloading File \"{0}\" from \"{1}\" .......\n\n", fileName, myStringWebResource);

        // Download the Web resource and save it into the current filesystem folder.
        myWebClient.DownloadFile(myStringWebResource, fileName);
        Console.WriteLine("Successfully Downloaded File \"{0}\" from \"{1}\"", fileName, myStringWebResource);
        Console.WriteLine("\nDownloaded file saved in the following file system folder:\n\t" + Application.StartupPath);

    }
```

Comment: so what's the value of `myStringWebResource` when you step through the debugger.. try a google search on `WebClient.DownLoadFile Ftp` here is something to look at in the meantime http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994486/c-sharp-webclient-stream-download-file-from-ftp-to-local-storage

Comment: What exception are you getting? Include message string, exception type, exception callstack. What is exactly a value of the `fileName` and `remoteUri`?